# Como relacionar tabelas

Tags: banco-de-dados

Boa tarde.

Tenho três tabelas: tbl_alunos, tbl_responsavel_financeiro, tbl_responsavel_pedagogico.

O ideia é que um aluno tenha um responsável financeiro e um responsável pedagógico.

Mas ocorrem três situações:

A) Um aluno pode ser responsável por ele mesmo, tanto na parte financeira quanto na pedagogica.

B) Uma única pessoa pode ser responsável por um aluno, tanto na parte financeira quanto na parte pedagógica.

C) Um responsável pode responder por mais de um aluno (no caso de um pai e vários filhos).

Então não estou conseguindo montar a estrutura de forma que fique coerente.P or exemplo:

- Na situação A, acabo tendo que criar os dados na tabela de alunos e repetir os mesmos dados nas demais tabelas. Pois o aluno é responsável por ele mesmo.
- Na situação B, tenho que criar os mesmos dados nas tabelas de responsável financeiro e pedagógico. Pois uma mesma pessoa faz o papel dos dois responsáveis.

Da forma que eu pensei (criando a tbl_alunos com chaves estrangeiras das tabelas tbl_responsavel_financeiro e tbl_responsavel_pedagogico, não está nada bom). Assim assumimos que pode existir um aluno com 0, 1 ou mais responsáveis.

Mas considerando que não exista aluno sem responsável, mudaria completamente os relacionamentos que criei.

Como eu poderia criar as tabelas e os relacionamentos, mas atendendo as três situações, sem repetir informações e que fique coerente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie apenas uma tabela unificando os cadastros de aluno, financeiro e pedagógico com alguma coluna que referencie qual o tipo de cadastro ai simplesmente adicione uma coluna de responsável financeiro com relação dela para ela mesmo, algo mais ou menos assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Claro e as demais informações da sua tabela.

Por exemplo:
Vamos começar a tratar os registros como pessoa para não confundir
Então teriamos 3 pessoas como exemplo, onde o 1 seria responsável por ele mesmo nos 2 casos
o 2 teria como responsável a pessoa 1 e ele mesmo e o 3 teria como responsável ele mesmo e o 2. E o aluno 4 não teria responsáveis.

ai você teria no campo tipo, o tipo de pessoa que é aquele registro, se for necessário no seu caso.

ID | TIPO | NOME | RESP FIN | RESP PEDA |

1  | Aluno | Pessoa 1 | 1 | 1 |

2  | Aluno | Pessoa 2 | 1 | 2 |

3  | Aluno | Pessoa 3 | 3 | 1 |

4  | Aluno | Pessoa 3 | null | null |

Comment: Pelo que entendi, isso resolveria o problema de o aluno ser ele mesmo o responsável.

Mas e para os casos em que aluno, responsável financeiro e responsável pedagógico forem pessoas diferentes?

Comment: salvei como edição para ficar melhor, um exemplo @bur

Comment: Maravilha! Caiu como uma luva. Desta forma (pelo que entendi, auto relacionamento) faz todo o sentido. Vou inserir o resto dos campos e prosseguir. Obrigado!

Comment: Isso mesmo, de nada!